# Playing and stopping sound on in Blender game engine

Tags: python, game-engine, audio

I'm setting up an audio book of sorts in BGE. I'm wanting to be able to click on a button to play a sound until the end, unless I click on a different button before the sound ends. If i click on the second button I want the first button to stop making it's sound.

If i set the sound actuator to Play Stop then i have to hold the button down to listen to it all. Then if I set the sound actuator to Play End and click on different buttons, then all the sounds play over each other.

I would prefer to be able to do this with just using the logic bricks, but do i have to use a python text to get it to do what i want?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple: use properties.

When you click, you set the property "sound" to then respective number of sound. Then, you check the property value with "Property" sensors and play sound 1 if property = 1, play sound 2 if property = 2 and so on.

Here's a working example file: [image]

Comment: Recommended to use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for example blend files.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @batFINGER, just updated the answer.